# Whenever I enable a service bus backplane in my application SignalR stops working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, servicebus

Whenever I enable a service bus backplane in my application SignalR stops working.

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(new ServiceBusScaleoutConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"].ToString()
                , System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["deployedApp"].ToString()));
```

I have Azure Service Bus 1.1 installed on Windows Server 2012, and it has created the necessary SbGateway, SbManagementDB, and SBMessageContainer01 databases on the SQL server.

I was able to turn on logging for SignalR hub code and the error says...

SignalR.ServiceBusMessageBus Error: 0 : Failed to create service bus subscription or topic : The timeout elapsed upon attempting to obtain a token while accessing 'https:.......

-Edit: Sorry looks like this message is actually the first to occur
SignalR.ServiceBusMessageBus Error: 0 : Failed to create service bus subscription or topic : The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://x.x.x.x/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/$STS/Windows/'. Token provider returned message: 'Unable to connect to the remote server'.

How do I set up my MVC application running under service account X or my own personal active directory account (when under local development conditions) to be allowed access to the service bus?

Comment: Do you have anything else amqp 'ish installed?  I have lots of issues when I had ServiceBus and RabbitMQ both installed.  I had to uninstall RabbitMQ.

Comment: @granadaCoder no I don't, it's essentially a clean installation of windows server with iis. The service bus is the only instance of an amqp installed to my knowledge.

Comment: Did you install the PUBLIC key version of the certificate "FirstMachineIInstalledServiceBusOn.fullyqualified.domainname.com" on the "client machine"........  Look in the certificate store of the first machine you installed Service Bus on.  The cert subject-name will start with the actual computer-name....in a fully qualified version.

Comment: Find my article here:  https://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2016/11/04/service-bus-and-custom-self-signed-certificates-with-a-high-availabilitymultiple-computing-nodes-in-the-farm/  and find the "RemoteCertificateValidationCallback" code.........that will help you debug the issue.

Comment: @granadaCoder thanks! Hopefully I can look into it this week and I'll let you know my findings.